# PHP multiplication

Tags: php, string, multiplication

It is my first question, so hi all..

Is it possible to satisfy this condition?
Where $a and $b are some defined variables

```
if(!is_numeric($a * $b.'')) { ... }
```

EDIT: Second conditon

```
$a * $b can't be INF
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I need it for some task, and I have no idea how to do it..
IMO it is impossible

Comment: Well * has higher precedence than . so I'd expect the multiplication to be executed then appending '' to the result should force the result datatype to be a string.... but the value of the result would still be a numeric (unless the $a and $b were too large and the result was INFINITY... and in that case, I think the resulting condition would be non-numeric)

Comment: @non you should have tried [this](http://codepad.org/JW2VTjjM) before posting it as a question

Comment: Mark Baker: OK :)
and if I add one more condition?

Jeroen: nothing.. it is only condition, I have to set $a and $b..

Comment: @optimusprime619: you are wrong, i need satisfy "!is_numeric"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can satisfy the condition with specific values of `$a` and `$b`. For example, `$a = $b = 1e200`, or `$a = 1e400, $b = 0`.

If the product of `$a` and `$b` overflows to infinity or is a not-a-number, the concatenation with an empty string will produce the string `INF` or `NAN`:

```
php > var_export(1e200*1e200);
INF
php > var_export(is_numeric(1e200*1e200));
true
php > var_export(is_numeric(1e200*1e200.''));
false

php > var_export(1e400*0);
NAN
php > var_export(is_numeric(1e400*0));
true
php > var_export(is_numeric(1e400*0 .''));
false
```

Answer (score 4):

Tested using 32-bit PHP

```
$a = 9.9E300;
$b = 9.9E300;

if(!is_numeric($a * $b.'')) {
    echo 'non-numeric';
} else {
    echo 'numeric';
}
```

Comment: Hm, I hadn't thought of that. +1